# systemd networkd and/or resolved blocking receiving (raw) packets on virtual network interface?

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-networkd, systemd-resolved, macvlan

While working on some unit test code that basically sends raw Ethernet packets from one MACVLAN to another MACVLAN (virtual) network interface I noticed that most of the time the test code fails to receive any of the packets sent from the first to the second MACVLAN. Using Wireshark I could see that the packets leave the first MACVLAN, but never reach the second MACVLAN or the listening raw socket. Only in a few odd instances do any packets go through at all -- without any change in the test code.

The host system is Ubuntu 22.10 (kernel 5.19.0-38-generic) with **systemd** and **network manager**.

Only after some time systemd-resolved, systemd-networkd and network manager arose my suspicion. By running the test in its own isolated transient network namespace I could successfully establish that out of the reach of these host services the test always correctly succeeds.

Suspecting network manager -- even if `nmcli device status` tells me that the virtual dummy and MACVLAN interfaces are "unmanaged -- I found https://developer-old.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/NetworkManager.conf.html and then added wildcards for unmanaged devices:

```
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=interface-name:docker*;interface-name:br-*;interface-name:veth*;interface-name:mcvl-*;interface-name:dumy-*
```

Unfortunately, this didn't improve the situation and the test was still failing on almost every run (even after restarting network manager multiple times and making sure that the config file is correct).

In Wireshark I noticed MDNS broadcasts on the MACVLAN network interfaces where there shouldn't be any. How can I tell both systemd's networkd as well as resolved to keep their dirty paws off any virtual network interface, especially dummy, MACVLAN and VETH network interfaces? I searched for configuration options but couldn't find anything suitable.

Any idea how to keep systemd's component off of things they should never touch in the first place?

The following is a Ginkgo/Gomega-based unit test that reproduces the situation.

```go
package pingpong

import (
    "bytes"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"

    "github.com/mdlayher/ethernet"
    "github.com/mdlayher/packet"
    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/dummy"
    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/link"
    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/macvlan"
    "github.com/thediveo/notwork/netns"
    "github.com/vishvananda/netlink"

    . "github.com/onsi/ginkgo/v2"
    . "github.com/onsi/gomega"
    . "github.com/thediveo/success"
)

func TestPingPong(t *testing.T) {
    RegisterFailHandler(Fail)
    RunSpecs(t, "pingpong package")
}

const (
    experimentalEthType = 0xffee // something (hopefully) unused
    pings               = 10
    pingInterval        = 100 * time.Millisecond
)

var payload = bytes.Repeat([]byte("HELO"), 100)

var _ = Describe("pingponging netdevs", Ordered, func() {

    BeforeAll(func() {
        if os.Geteuid() != 0 {
            Skip("needs root")
        }
    })

    DescribeTable("virtual network pingpong",
        func(ctx context.Context, dropall bool) {
            // By("creating a new network namespace")
            // defer netns.EnterTransientNetns()()

            By("creating two MACVLANs connected via a dummy network interface")
            dummy := dummy.NewTransientUp()
            macvlan1 := macvlan.NewTransient(dummy)
            netlink.LinkSetUp(macvlan1)
            macvlan2 := macvlan.NewTransient(dummy)
            netlink.LinkSetUp(macvlan2)

            macvlan1 = Successful(netlink.LinkByIndex(macvlan1.Attrs().Index))
            mac1 := macvlan1.Attrs().HardwareAddr

            macvlan2 = Successful(netlink.LinkByIndex(macvlan2.Attrs().Index))
            mac2 := macvlan2.Attrs().HardwareAddr

            Expect(mac1).NotTo(Equal(mac2))

            By(fmt.Sprintf("waiting for MACVLANs (%s-%s, %s-%s) to become operationally UP",
                macvlan1.Attrs().Name, macvlan1.Attrs().HardwareAddr.String(),
                macvlan2.Attrs().Name, macvlan2.Attrs().HardwareAddr.String()))
            link.EnsureUp(macvlan1)
            link.EnsureUp(macvlan2)

            By("opening data-link layer sockets")
            txconn := Successful(packet.Listen(
                &net.Interface{Index: macvlan1.Attrs().Index}, packet.Raw, experimentalEthType, nil))
            defer txconn.Close()
            rxconn := Successful(packet.Listen(
                &net.Interface{Index: macvlan2.Attrs().Index}, packet.Raw, experimentalEthType, nil))
            defer rxconn.Close()

            ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(ctx)
            defer cancel()

            By("sending data-link layer PDUs")
            go func() {
                defer cancel()
                defer GinkgoRecover()
                f := ethernet.Frame{
                    Destination: mac2,
                    Source:      mac1,
                    EtherType:   experimentalEthType,
                    Payload:     payload,
                }
                frame := Successful(f.MarshalBinary())
                toAddr := packet.Addr{HardwareAddr: mac2}
                for i := 0; i < pings; i++ {
                    By("sending something...")
                    _, err := txconn.WriteTo(frame, &toAddr)
                    Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
                    select {
                    case <-ctx.Done():
                        return
                    case <-time.After(pingInterval):
                    }
                }
            }()

            By("receiving data-link layer PDUs (or not)")
            received := 0
        receive:
            for {
                buffer := make([]byte, 1500)
                rxconn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now().Add(1 * time.Second))
                n, fromAddr, err := rxconn.ReadFrom(buffer)
                select {
                case <-ctx.Done():
                    break receive
                default:
                }
                if err != nil && dropall && strings.Contains(err.Error(), "i/o timeout") {
                    continue
                }
                Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
                By("...received something")
                f := ethernet.Frame{}
                Expect(f.UnmarshalBinary(buffer[:n])).To(Succeed())
                Expect(f.EtherType).To(Equal(ethernet.EtherType(experimentalEthType)))
                Expect(fromAddr.(*packet.Addr).HardwareAddr).To(Equal(mac1))
                Expect(f.EtherType).To(Equal(ethernet.EtherType(experimentalEthType)))
                Expect(len(f.Payload)).To(BeNumerically(">=", len(payload)))
                Expect(f.Payload[:len(payload)]).To(Equal(payload))
                received++
            }

            if !dropall {
                Expect(received).To(BeNumerically(">=", (2*pings)/3), "too much packet loss")
            } else {
                Expect(received).To(BeZero())
            }

        },
        Entry("receives passed-on packets", false),
    )

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took some time to have the correct inspiration that maybe there was something about the MAC addresses, so I added this safeguard expectation that then immediately triggered:

```go
mac2 := Successful(netlink.LinkByIndex(macvlan2.Attrs().Index)).
    Attrs().HardwareAddr

// ... something going on here

mac2now := Successful(netlink.LinkByIndex(macvlan2.Attrs().Index)).
    Attrs().HardwareAddr
Expect(mac2now).To(Equal(mac2))
```

Looking through especially the few `*.link` configurations in especially `/usr/lib/systemd/network/` there's a catch-all default configuration in `99-default.link` that is as follows:

```ini
[Match]
OriginalName=*

[Link]
NamePolicy=keep kernel database onboard slot path
AlternativeNamesPolicy=database onboard slot path
MACAddressPolicy=persistent
```

So what does `MACAddressPolicy=persistent` actually do? The [networkd link documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html#%5BLink%5D%20Section%20Options) explains:

> If the hardware has a persistent MAC address, as most hardware should, and if it is used by the kernel, nothing is done. Otherwise, a new MAC address is generated which is guaranteed to be the same on every boot for the given machine and the given device, but which is otherwise random.

So, `networkd` (or is it actually `udevd`?) is replacing the original MAC address of any new MACVLAN netdev with another one.

As this takes some time from where the MACVLAN comes up the unit test has queried the original MAC addresses and by the time the test starts sending Ethernet packets, the second MACVLAN's MAC address has changed, so that the original destination MAC has been gone with the test unaware of this.

A fix is to at least selectively revert the `MACAddressPolicy=` to `none`, for instance:

```ini
# /etc/systemd/network/00-notwork.link
[Match]
Kind=macvlan
OriginalName=mcvl-*

[Link]
Description="keep systemd's sticky fingers off test netdevs"
MACAddressPolicy=none
```